# Add space between NavigationStack toolbar and other elements

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-toolbar

I am trying to add space between the yellow toolbar and the MiniView element below. When I add space, it looks like it extends the toolbar.

The space needs to be similar to the space between the MiniView and List.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnotherView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        let words = ["Nakul", "Chawla"]
        
        VStack {
           
            
            VStack{
                Text("lets see if this works")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hawaii")
            .toolbar {
                Text("something else")
            }
            .toolbarBackground(.yellow, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                MiniView()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                List(words, id: \.self) { word in
                    Text(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: UI screen]

EDIT:
screenshot from another app to demonstrate what I want.
Something like this but instead of the first list, I want a VStack where I can add some information.

[image]

Comment: Try adding , for example: `.padding(.top, 22)` to your `VStack` with the `Text("lets see if this works")`

Comment: t adds the space within the top part, but doesn't separate it like how the list is separate from the toolbar.

Comment: can you show a picture of what you want

Comment: I added one more screenshot. It if from Todoist app. Its a parent view but I want something similar in a child view.

Comment: You could try `VStack(spacing: 33) {
 Spacer()
 VStack {
     Text("lets see if this works") ....` to have a space between the `yellow` toolbar and the second `VStack`.

Comment: Any kind of spacing I add only stretches the box. It doesn't create space between the elements.